# Display custom attributes before WooCommerce upsells ( linked products)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-attributes, product

I manage to display the custom attributes but they are shown after linked products how can I make them appear before?

On the left: what I currently have, right desired result

Thanks
[image]

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, thanks for your guidance

Comment: Ok.. the position is figured out but now I can't display the custom attribute of the post, I had this piece of code on single-product.php which I had moved to mu functions.php file: add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'custom_code_after_single_product_summary', 12 );
function custom_code_after_single_product_summary() {
    global $product;
    // ===> Your code goes here
   
 echo '<p>Product ID: '. get_post_meta($post->ID, 'TABLE', true).'</p>'; 
 
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look to the woocommerce template content-single-product.php you will see that:

```
/**
 * woocommerce_after_single_product_summary hook.
 *
 * @hooked woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs - 10
 * @hooked woocommerce_upsell_display - 15
 * @hooked woocommerce_output_related_products - 20
 */
do_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary' );
```

That means that in the **`woocommerce_after_single_product_summary`** hook, the following is displayed:

1. First (with a priority of 10) The product tabs,
2. Then (with a priority of 15) The upsells,
3. And to finish (with a priority of 20) The related products.

So if you want to display your custom code between the product tabs and the upsells, you will need to use a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_after_single_product_summary`** action hook with a priority between 11 to 14.

You can do it this way:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'custom_code_after_single_product_summary', 12 );
function custom_code_after_single_product_summary() {
    global $product;

    // Set here your post "meta_key" for your custom product attribute
    $meta_key1 = 'pa_when-to-use';

    // Your code (related to your comment):
    echo get_post_meta($product->get_id(),  $meta_key1, true);
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works on WooCommerce 3+…

Comment: Ok.. the position is figured out but now I can't display the custom attribute of the post, I had this piece of code on single-product.php:  <?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'TABLE', true); ?>, where 'TABLE' is the name of the custom attribute

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: This is working for me. Thanks, upvote from my side